# after(:each) vs after(:all) in Rails rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rspec

In rails rspec, I am writing test cases that do this:

```
after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end
```

I need the database to be cleaned after each test is run. But will this affect the performance of my tests and make them slower?

Comment: Is your question "If my computer has to do more stuff, will that take longer than when it does less stuff"?  If so then yes, obviously.

Comment: but is it going to slow down my tests significantly, and is using after(:each) a bad practice

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "significantly".  I think you will notice the difference.  Why don't you just try it and see, and then you can decide whether you can put up with it?

Comment: Try `DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:transaction)` after each test. It will speed up your tests a little bit (But if you are playing with `EventMachine`, transaction strategy may not work, so you have to stick to truncation strategy). AFAIK clean up database after each test is a good practice, because it removes false green caused by historical data in database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "truncation" method has an impact based on the number of tables, because it will execute one query per table to truncate. You can use the "transaction" method instead, which will do a transaction-based rollback instead, which will drastically decrease the amount of resources used to roll back to a clean database state.

If you use ActiveRecord and want to have a clear picture of what happens, you can do something like this in your test:

```
before do
  ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It will have impact on performance depending on the number of tests on which the `after` hook will be run.

Also, I think it is best to use `before` instead of `after`. Depending on the test case, the state of the database is a precondition; the test case requires that precondition. And you should ensure that precondition with the `before` hook instead of relying on `after` hooks defined somewhere else.